# matplotlib animation doesn't animate with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, imshow

I'm trying to animate a few simple subplots with imshow but there's apparently an issue.

This is a small demo of my problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation    

fig,axs=plt.subplots(2,5,figsize=(10,4))
imgs=[]

for row in axs:
    for col in row:
        col.set_xlim(4.5,-.5)
        col.set_ylim(4.5,-.5)
        col.set_xticks([])
        col.set_yticks([])

        #line A
        imgs.append(col.imshow([[]],animated=1))
        #freezes the animation([[]] is just a placeholder)

        #line B
        #imgs.append(col.imshow(np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)),animated=1))
        #animation does work if the above line is used instead

def func(frm):
    for i in range(10):
        imgs[i].set_array(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)*np.log10(frm+1))
    return imgs
anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func,10,interval=100)
plt.show()
```

If  I use line A, the animation freezes as if **func** is not executed (while actually it is), raising no errors. If line B is used instead, the animation works. Am I missing something about **imshow** animating?

Comment: The code you show is not runnable. But the problem seems to be that you effectively initialize the imshow plot with color limits of vmin=0, vmax=0. You can set `vmax=24` to achieve the same result as with the commented out code.

Comment: Oh, so that's the piece I'm missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also,if the **np.zeros((5,5))** part is replaced with **[[[]]** the animation freezes as well, even with the *vmax* option. Why is that exactly?

Comment: `[[[]]]` is a 3D array, for which vmax is ignored because no colorscaling takes place for 3D arrays.

Comment: Oops, I sould've typed **[[]]**, which freezes the animation

Comment: I suggest you first make the code runnable (see [mcve]). Then we can see what problem you face. Note though that `[[]]` is an image of no extent, so it may simply not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Animation from multiple *imshow* can be created by [ArtistAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.html) object using multiple axes generated by *subplots* command.

```
from numpy import random
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_lst_1 = [random.random((368,1232)) for i in range(10)] # Test data
img_lst_2 = [random.random((368,1232)) for i in range(10)] # Test data

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
frames = [] # store generated images
for i in range(len(img_lst_1)):
    
    img1 = ax1.imshow(img_lst_1[i], animated=True)
    img2 = ax2.imshow(img_lst_2[i], cmap='gray', animated=True)
    
    frames.append([img1, img2])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames, interval=500, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)
ani.save('movie_example.mp4')
```

Code output:

[image]